# Como validar un correo electrónico en un formulario de contacto con PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, css, formularios

Tengo una duda sobre como Validar un correo electrónico, Ya que que quisiera que el mensaje de contacto se envié solo cuando el correo sea verdadero, Estoy haciéndolo con PHPMailer pero me envía sin importar la veracidad del correo. Ademas que no quisiera ser victima de bots.
Me gustaría saber cual es la mejor forma de hacer un formulario de contacto con el cual solo se envié el mensaje si el correo electrónico existe y no ser victima de bots.

Aqui les dejo el codigo de php.

```html
<?php
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$correo = $_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];


$body =  "Nombre: " . $nombre . "<br>Correo: " . $correo . "<br>Mensaje: " . $mensaje;



use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                  
    $mail->isSMTP();                               
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';        
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->Username   = 'direccion1@gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Password   = '*********';                                
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('direccion1@gmail.com', $nombre);
    $mail->addAddress('direccion2@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Correo de la pagina Sial';
    $mail->Body    = $body;

    $mail->send();
    echo '<script>
      alert("El mensaje fue enviado correctamente");
      window.history.go(-1);
      </script>

    ';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Si no quieres ser victima de un bot, puedes utilizar un captcha, puedes obtener más información [aqui](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPmailer solo se encarga de enviar los correos, no va a validar si este existe o no.

Para validar, hay una librería que en principio se encarga de ello, tienes un ejemplo del código en esta web aunque no es 100% fiable.
https://programacion.net/articulo/como_verificar_una_direccion_de_correo_y_comprobar_si_es_real_utilizando_php_2069

Otra cosa que debes hacer es comprobar si la direccion de correo esta bien formada con por ejemplo

```
filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Me imagino que el dato te llega por post

y por último, muy recomendable poner en tu formulario un captcha para ver que es humano el que realiza el envío

**EDITO para añadir la respuesta a la pregunta que hace @DanielReyes**
Para validar los campos lo puedes hacer de dos formas, todos los campos juntos como en la primera sentencia if, o campo a campo como en la segunda, o mezclar.
En el primer if ademas válido que sea un correo electrónico bien formado

```
if (empty($_POST['name']) || 
     empty($_POST['email']) || 
     !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    echo "No se han enviado argmentos!"; 
    return false; } 

  if (empty($_POST['provincia'])) { 
    echo "No se ha enviado dato provincia!"; 
    return false; 
   }
```

Otra cosa que es recomendable hacer, es usar en el formulario un poco de html5 poniendo en los campos input un required aunque siempre hay que validar los datos del lado del servidor en el script que ejecuta cualquier acción

Comment: Para que es el código que me pasaste.? para validar si esta escrito bien un correo.? o me equivoco. Gracias chequeare esa librería soy nuevo con esto de php comencé hace nada así que muchas gracias. Solo quiero saber para que es el codigo que me pasaste.

Comment: Si, el código es para verificar que está bien escrito el correo

Comment: Una ultima pregunta como valido que todos los campos están completos y no se envié hasta que todos este completos te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

A los bots de los spammers les da igual poner un email correcto aunque sea inventado, porque ya te están enviando su mensaje y los enlaces a sus sitios web en la variable `$mensaje`.

En la práctica es inviable validar una dirección de email. Puedes validar su sintaxis (que no es trivial) y que el dominio tenga un MX que responda, pero eso no te dice si la dirección existe (aunque puedes hacer una conexión SMTP y ver cómo responde el servidor destino al comando `RCPT TO`, esa respuesta no es concluyente) ni si corresponde a la persona que dice haber escrito.

Además posiblemente no quieres rechazar los mensajes de la gente que escribe mal su dirección (hotamil.com, gemail.com, etc.) especialmente si estás vendiendo algo.

Si la cosa se pone fea, te recomiendo que pongas un *captcha*, y no necesariamente para los usuarios de todos los países.

Comment: Lo que quiero es no ser victimas de bots y esas cosas, Como me das entender creo que es necesario poner un captcha.